# Cloudberry - Unable to mount drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, cloudberry

```
I used below commands to add cloudberry drive and to mount it,
.\cbd.exe addDrive -d G -an CloudBerryDrive -path "cberrybucket/BerryTest" - 
label "CloudBerryVolume" -rrs yes
.\cbd.exe mountDrive G
And when I try to mount the drive, it gives the below error
**"Drive not mounted. See logs for details."**
```

I created an EC2 Windows Instance in which I installed Cloudberry.

Comment: *"See logs for details."*  What's in the logs?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).